# Rails select field from intermiate table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models: `Plan` and `Service`.

In `Plan` model y have:

```
has_many :plan_services
has_many :services, through: :plan_services
```

And in `Service` model y have:

```
has_many :plan_services
has_many :plans, through: :plan_services
```

And I have a extra field in `plan_services` table called `quantity` like:

```
plan_id: 1
service_id: 1
quantity: 3
```

Then I want get all services from plan with `quantity` field like:
`@plan.services.map{|s| s.quantity}`

But doesn't work.

How could I get this field in the relation?

Comment: Why not go through @play.plan_services?

Comment: Yes @dbugger, I'm doing this like you comment but I asked out of curiosity if It could be done differently

Comment: Possibly, but this is the most straightforward approach.

Comment: you can use this also ... *@plan.services.where("plan_services. quantity =?", your_quantity_param)*

Answer (score 0):

```
@plan.services.map{|s| s.quantity}
```

It will not work because @plan.services gives you objects of `service` class and not the `plan_service` class. You are not having quantity column in service table.

One more thing I noticed is that you are having only two models instead of three, You have to define intermediate table as you are using `has_many :through` association.

In your case, add `plan_service.rb` file in `app/models` and put following lines to it.

```
class PlanService < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :plan
  belongs_to :services
end
```

If you don't need this model as an independent entity then you can use `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship.

Comment: He does need the model. He has quantity field and cannot use HABTM.

Answer (score 0):

I think you already have `PlanService` model mentioned by @TejasviniParikh

```
@plan.plan_services.map { |ps| ps.quantity }
```

should work if you need only quantity in the select.

inlcude `includes(:service)` before map if you want to use any field of service in select.

e.g.

```
@plan.plan_services.includes(:service).map { |ps| "#{ps.service.name} #{ps.quantity}" }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `@plan.plan_services.pluck(:quantity)` should do the job.

`map` will work on `ruby` level and is really slow.

If you want to query on the `quantity` field, you can do it like:

```
@plan.plan_services.where(quantity: 1..3) # where quantity is in range of 1 to 3

@plan.plan_services.where(quantity: 1) # where 1
```